How to show that $\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^{25}(\theta)\sin(17\theta)d\theta = \frac{\binom{25}{4}\pi}{2^{24}} \approx 2.37 \times 10^{-3} $?
I've been trying to solve this integral for days and the mark scheme provided doesn't help
The question states that you should use these formulae (without proof) below
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(m\theta)\sin(n\theta)d\theta=0 \\ 
\sin^5(\theta)=\frac{1}{16}\left(\sin(5\theta)+5\sin(3\theta)+10\sin(\theta)\right)$$
I attempted the question and I'm not sure where I went wrong
The mark scheme says that $\frac{1}{2^{24}}\binom{25}{4}\pi$ is the solution but it doesn't explain where it comes from or how to get to that result

Hi, welcome to Math SE. $\sin^{25}\theta=(\sin^5\theta)^n$ for $n=5$, not $n=2$.

$\sin(x)^{25}=(\sin(x)^5)^5$ not $(\sin(x)^5)^2$ so you'll have even more terms. I don't know if it is possible to speed up things and focus only on the constant term though without developing all expressions.

This problem is a trap ! The integrand is a linear combination $\sum_{n=0}^{21} a_n, \cos(2 n x)$. "Just" find the $a_0$.

@Svyatoslav. How would you get the constant term ? (look at my previous comment)

My apology; made a typo. Should be
$$\sin^{2k+1}(x)=\frac{(-1)^k}{2^{2k+1}i}\sum_{l=0}^{2k+1}\binom{2k+1}{l}(-1)^{l}e^{ix(2k+1-2l)}$$
$$\int_0^{2\pi}e^{\pm imx}dx=0 ,,\text{at} ,,m=1,2,3,...,,\text{and},,=2\pi,,\text{at},, m=0$$

Considering $,\sin^{2k+1}x\sin(2m+1)x$, we get, at the fixed $m$, the terms
$$\int_0^{2\pi}e^{ix(2k+1-2l)}\big(e^{(2m+1)xi}-e^{-(2m+1)xi}\big)dx$$
which are non-zero at $2k-2l-2m=0,,\Rightarrow,,l=k-m,$ and at $,2k-2l+2m+2=0,,\Rightarrow,,l=m+k+1,$. Both surviving after the integration terms have the same sign (due to the factor $(-1)^l,$), and are equal.

@Claude Leibovici, thank you for you comment. I corrected a typo. Two terms survive after the integration and are equal, so the answer is not zero )

@Svyatoslav. The answer in he post is correct. I was wondering how to quickly obtain the $a_0$ in the linear cobination of $\cos(2nx)$. That's all.

In this solution I am using the Euler's formula and binomial theorem, which would be computationally simpler than (although equivalent to) using multiple angle formula of sine.
$$I = \int_0^{2\pi} \sin^{25}\theta \sin(17 \theta) d\theta$$
$$ = \int_0^{2\pi} \left(\frac{e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}}{2i}\right)^{25} \sin(17 \theta) d\theta$$
$$ = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{e^{25 i\theta}}{2^{25}i}(1-e^{-2i\theta})^{25} \sin(17 \theta) d\theta$$
When multiplied with $\sin(17 \theta)$ and integrated from $0$ to $2\pi$, only $e^{17i\theta}$ and $e^{-17i\theta}$ will produce a non-zero result.
From the binomial theorem, the coefficient of $e^{17i\theta}$ in $e^{25 i\theta}(1-e^{-2i\theta})^{25} $ is $\binom{25}{4}$, and that of $e^{-17i\theta}$ is $-\binom{25}{21}=-\binom{25}{4}$.
Therefore, the integral is,
$$I = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\binom{25}{4}}{2^{25}i}(e^{17i\theta}-e^{-17i\theta}) \sin(17 \theta) d\theta$$
(all other terms would integrate to zero)
$$ = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\binom{25}{4}}{2^{24}}\sin^2(17 \theta) d\theta$$
$$ = \boxed{\frac{\binom{25}{4}\pi}{2^{24}}}.$$

Complex method: Let $z=e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$, then $z^{17}=\cos(17x)+i\sin(17x)$ and
$$\sin x=\frac1{2i}\left(z-\frac1z\right),\quad 
\sin(17x)=\frac1{2i}\left(z^{17}-\frac1{z^{17}}\right).$$
So
$$I=\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^{25}(x)\sin(17x)dx
=\frac{1}{(2i)^{26}}\int_{|z|=1}\left(z-\frac1z\right)^{25}\left(z^{17}-\frac1{z^{17}}\right)\frac{dz}{iz}\\
=\frac{1}{i(2i)^{26}}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{(z^2-1)^{25}(z^{34}-1)}{z^{43}}dz.$$
Let $f(z)=\frac{(z^2-1)^{25}(z^{34}-1)}{z^{43}},$ then, by Residue theorem, we get
$$I=\frac{1}{i(2i)^{26}}\cdot2\pi i\cdot Res(f,0)=
\frac{1}{i(2i)^{26}}\cdot2\pi i\cdot\frac{1}{(42)!}g^{(42)}(0)\\
=\frac{1}{i(2i)^{26}}\cdot2\pi i\cdot\left[-2\binom{25}{4}\right]
=\frac{1}{2^{24}}\binom{25}{4}\pi,$$
where $g(z)=(z^2-1)^{25}(z^{34}-1)$(it is easy to compute that the coefficient of the term $z^{42}$ is $-2\binom{25}{4}$).

In your attempt, line 3:  how can $$\sin^{25}{\theta}=(\sin {5\theta})^2?$$
You can write $$\sin^{25}{\theta}=\\(\sin^{5}{\theta})^5=\\(\frac{1}{16}\left(\sin(5\theta)+5\sin(3\theta)+10\sin(\theta)\right)
)^5$$
